# HOW to back for the beginning if the user press any key except 1 or 2 or 3?

Tags: c, loops, user-input

In the code bellow the user will enter 1 or 2 or 3 and it will be taken by getch and after that the program will enter to switch ....but i have a problem
after applying any case of switch i want to make the program back to the beginning if the user press any key ?

the c language is still new for me so it will be great if you explain in 
   simple way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    char L;

    while (1) {
        L = getch();

        switch (L) {
        case '1':
            system("cls"); 
            printf("111111111111111");
            break;
        case '2':
            system("cls");
            printf("222222222222222");
            break;
        case '3':
            system("cls");
            printf("33333333");
            break;
        default:
            sleep(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation..........................

Comment: Please edit the question and indent your code.

Comment: Please edit the question and indent your code. As it is now, is hard to understand what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `do`-`while` loop and set the condition to `while(L != '1' && L != '2' && L != '3');`:

```
do {
    L = getch();
    switch (L) {
    case '1' :
        system("cls"); 
        printf("111111111111111");
        break;
    case '2' :
        system("cls");
        printf("222222222222222");
        break;
    case '3' :
        system("cls");
        printf("33333333");
        break;
    default :
        sleep(0);
    }
} while(L != '1' && L != '2' && L != '3');
```

The code above will prompt for data first then evaluate it and continue these until user enters `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'`.

---

As comments bellow mention the `default` case with `sleep(0)` has no use but it can be improved e.g. as follows:

```
do {
    L = getch();
    switch (L) {
    case '1' :
        system("cls"); 
        printf("111111111111111");
        break;
    case '2' :
        system("cls");
        printf("222222222222222");
        break;
    case '3' :
        system("cls");
        printf("33333333");
        break;
    default :
        L = 0;
    }
} while(!L);
```

In this example you don't have to double check for permitted values (assuming that you don't want to use the case when `L == 0`).

---

As the title of your question is a bit misleading maybe I didn't understand what do you like to achieve. If you just want to suspend going back to the beginning of your loop, you can add an extra `getch()` after the `switch` block:

```
while (1) {
    L = getch();

    switch (L) {
    case '1':
        system("cls"); 
        printf("111111111111111");
        break;
    case '2':
        system("cls");
        printf("222222222222222");
        break;
    case '3':
        system("cls");
        printf("33333333");
        break;
    }

    printf("Press Any Key to Continue...");
    getch();
}
```

If this still doesn't answer your question I recommend you to improve it.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason of downvote.

Comment: What's the reason for the `sleep(0)`? (BTW I upvoted).

Comment: @MichaelWalz Just copied it from the question and did not consider it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz sleep for 0 seconds, it's useless. Maybe it used the sleep(0) just to have a statement on default case.

Comment: the work of sleep() at the beginning if the user press any key except 1,2,3 nothing will happen

Comment: @martenmarteny If you don't want to do anything in `default` case, then simply don't insert it into your `switch` statement. A `switch` without `default` case is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the switch-case with a `while` loop. E.g.:

```
int done = 0;
while(!done) {
    L = getch();
    switch (L) {
    case '1' :
        system("cls"); 
        printf("111111111111111");
        done = 1;
        break;
    case '2' :
        system("cls");
        printf("222222222222222");
        done = 1;
        break;
    case '3' :
        system("cls");
        printf("33333333");
        done = 1;
        break;
    default :
        sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work i want after any case is applyed if the user press any key the program will back to the beginning ...

Comment: @martenmarteny You titled your question as the program get back to the beginning if the user presses any key **except** for 1, 2 or 3. But it looks like you want something much easier and different. If you wish to go back after a keypress whatever is done before just simply add an extra `getch()` to the end of your `while` loop.